# haskell problems with Data.Map update

Tags: opengl, haskell, dictionary

I am trying to edit the vertices. I can add to it, but when I use update I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)
                                  -> Maybe (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)'
                with actual type `(t0, t1, t2)'
    In the first argument of `Map.update', namely `(- 0.75, 0.25, 0.0)'
    In the expression: Map.update (- 0.75, 0.25, 0.0) "v1" faceMap
    In an equation for `it':
        it = Map.update (- 0.75, 0.25, 0.0) "v1" faceMap
```

---

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL

faceMap :: Map.Map [Char] (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)
faceMap = Map.fromList $
    [("v1", (-0.25, 0.25, 0.0 ))
    ,("v1", (0.75, 0.35, 0.0))
    ,("v3", (0.75, -0.15, 0.0))
    ,("v4", (-0.75, -0.25, 0.0))
    ]
```

---

If you know another way other than editing values that would be great, and yes this is OpenGL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Data.Map.update` is slightly different from `insert` (which should just work in your example if you swap arguments around).

- `insert` sets a value in a map, and if it's already there replaces it.
- `update` performs a lookup and uses a function to define what will happen with the value, basing on the previous value. It can either return `Nothing` to state the value for that key should be deleted, or `Just` new value.

Maybe type signatures will clarify better:

```
update :: Ord k => (a -> Maybe a) -> k -> Map k a -> Map k a
```

and

```
insert :: Ord k => k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a
```

Comment: @JoelWaterworth by using `insert`. Read the first paragraph again.